# Linq List in list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I've got a problem to combine two list in one query:

```
public class Class1 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Class2> attr { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 {
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

My query looks like that:

```
var q = (from m in context.table
                 select new Class1
                 {
                     id = m.ID,
                     attr = (from t in context.table2
                                 where m.id == t.id
                                 select new Class2 { 
                                    id= t.id
                                 }).Take(5).ToList()
                 }).Take(1).ToList();
```

Any solutions for this problem?

**Problem:**
My problem is that my result is always null. If i remove the second query

```
                     attr = (from t in context.table2
                                 where m.id == t.id
                                 select new Class2 { 
                                    id= t.id
                                 }).Take(5).ToList()
```

, my query works!

Comment: what is the problem? any error message?

Comment: i'm so sorry for my questions. i'm new in this forum.

Comment: @Calimero: You can edit your question to add the problem, then people will undo their downvotes and you'll get better response. Btw, as John has mentioned Stackoverflow is not an ordinary forum, see [Is Stack Overflow a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/147438).

Comment: the problem is, that the query doesn't work and my result is always null

Comment: i'm new in this site. *embarrassing*

Comment: I've prepared test model for your example and everything works well. I received resultset with only one item. Then the question is: What's wrong? (+1 for embarrassment)

Comment: @AnatoliiG: your test model has a second query with a join on the first table? mmhh...

Comment: @Calimero Yes, same. Copied from your post.

Comment: now i got the following error message:
"linq to entities does not recognize the method list...linq this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works perfectly (I replaced your `context` variable with my custom one), so , in my opinion, you would better check your `where` statements

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Class2> attr { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    class MyEntity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public MyEntity(int id)
        {
            ID = id;
        }
    }
    class MyContext : List<MyEntity>
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var context = new MyContext();
            context.Add(new MyEntity(1));
            context.Add(new MyEntity(2));
            context.Add(new MyEntity(3));
            context.Add(new MyEntity(4));
            context.Add(new MyEntity(5));

            var q = (from m in context
                     select new Class1
                     {
                         id = m.ID,
                         attr = (from t in context
                                 where m.ID == t.ID
                                 select new Class2
                                 {
                                     id = t.ID
                                 }).Take(5).ToList()
                     }).Take(1).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
 var listAB = listA.Cast<object>().Union(listB.Cast<object>()).ToLookup(x => x is TypeA ? (x as TypeA).Key : (x as TypeB).Key)
            .Select(kv => {
                var a = kv.FirstOrDefault(x => x is TypeA) as TypeA;
                var b = kv.FirstOrDefault(x => x is TypeB) as TypeB;
                return new TypeAB() {
                    Key = kv.Key,
                    ValueA = a != null ? (int?)a.Value : null,
                    ValueB = b != null ? (int?)b.Value : null
                };
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the soultion. instead of using a List<> i changed it to IQueryable<> and now it works.

i remember my error message: "linq to entities does not recognize the method list...linq this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

does anyone understand it?